# Meteor js - Template: multiple collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I have two collections:

- Posts: {_id: "123", text: "some text", user_id: "456"}
- Bookmarks: {_id: "456", post_id: "123", user_id: "425" }

In the Bookmarks collection the post_id is the _id from the bookmarked post.

I use the following template helper to display all posts by specific user:

```
Template.profile.helpers({
    posts: function () {

// get current router parameter id (iron router)
   context = Router.current().params._id;

   return Posts.find({user_id: context},   {sort: {timestamp: -1} } );
}
});
```

Now I would like to display all posts a user has bookmarked in a template: userBookmarks. Is it possible to achieve this with template helper ?
Or only with a package or the Mongo.Collection transform option ?

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<template name="userBookmarks">
  {{#each myBookmarks}}
    {{#with post}}
      {{text}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.userBookmarks.helpers({
  myBookmarks: function(){
    return Bookmarks.find({user_id: Meteor.userId()});
  },
  post: function(){
    return Posts.findOne({_id: this.post_id});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a one-helper version:

```
Template.userBookmarks.helpers({
  'posts': function () {
    return Posts.find({
      _id: {
        $in: Bookmarks.find({user_id: Meteor.userId()}).map(function (bookmark) {
          return bookmark.post_id;
        })
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, @MichelFloyd's version ends up doing more queries, but looks a lot nicer than my curly braces soup. Also it may work better reactively.